# Proguard runs every time with gradle; results not reused

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

I am building an Android app with gradle 1.8 and Android Gradle plugin 0.6.3.

```
android {       
        ...
        buildTypes {
        ... 
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFile 'proguard.cfg'
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
        ... 
}
```

Every time I run `gradle assembleRelease`, the proguard step seems to run each time - the results of the previous `assemble` do not seem to be reused, *despite no code changes*. The compile step also says `UP-TO-DATE`for subsequent runs, which seems to confirm this. Running proguard adds a significant amount of time to every build. In particular, running `connectedInstrumentTest` currently requires proguard to run each time.

Is this normal behavior when using proguard/gradle? If not, what are some things that could cause the proguard step to run each time?

Note: It is not actually possible for me to build my app without proguard shrinking anymore, the dex step fails with the following error:

```
trouble writing output: Too many method references: 67195; max is 65536.
```

Comment: Why do you so often call assembleRelease?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be solved when the Android Gradle task upgrades to the ProGuard Gradle task version 4.10. The latter has the necessary annotations for Gradle to check if the output is up to date.